# bios write protection

Tags: motherboard, bios, uefi, malware, write-protect

I read that bios attacks are popular since [1998](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIH_(computer_virus)). And I want to know if I can protect my motherboard some how:

```
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.
        Product Name: B75M-D3H
        Version: x.x
```

The current installed bios is:

```
BIOS Information
        Vendor: American Megatrends Inc.
        Version: F14
        Release Date: 04/17/2013
```

Can I enable any write protection to prevent the chipset of my  motherboard from any manipulation?

Comment: No. For some years now the BIOS is copied from an EProm (Flash storage) to a mapped piece of Ram before execution. There are protections in the mapping, but virtually all of these can be overcome unless you are using UEFI.

Comment: @JackCreasey Do you mean SMRAM? I know there where theoretical concepts already in [2009](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/sec.166/full) which became in proof e.g. by LightEater in 2015. Concept of the attack is independent of using bios or uefi. How get's the malicious code into SMRAM when is not stored somewhere permanently and how can I protect this permanent storage? I expected this storage is the same where the BIOS or UEFI is stored and I can enable any write protection for this storage.